# Breadcrumb Consistency / Ajax Form Post and History.Back()

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-interface

I am currently designing a web app that involves forms that are chained together.  For example:

Employees Grid > Single Employee Form with Leave Requests Grid > Single Leave Request Form with Alternative Employees Grid > Single Employee Form...

My problem is how to manage the back button.  If the user performs the following actions:

- Open Single Employee Form from Employees Grid. *[Back would take them
  to the Employees Grid.]*
- Open a Single Leave Request Form from the
  Employee Form *[Back would take them to the Employee Form.]*
- Make a change to the Single Leave Request Form that posts and redirects to
  the Single Employee Form *[Back here would take them back to the
  Single Leave Request Form, then the Employee Form and then the Employees Grid.  Would they expect it
  to take them back to the Employees Grid?]*
- Open another Single Leave Request Form from the Employee Form, make a change that posts and
  redirects to the Single Employee Form. *[Back here would again take
  them back to the Single Leave Request Form, then the Employee Form,
  then the Single Leave Request Form, then the Employee Form and then
  the Employees Grid.  Would they expect it to take them back to the
  Employees Grid?]*

This chain could become very long.

One idea I had was to implement a behavior that adheres to the breadcrumb by posting forms using Ajax then calling history.back().  This open up another set of complications (what if the user has opened the page in a new tab/window or is using a bookmarked URL) but I believe this could be handled using the history.length and window.name properties.

Am I underestimating my users - would they know what to expect, or does this chain need to be simplified - and if so, do you think my solution will work?